# Xcode 4.2.3 App Not Running On iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have just started to learn how to code iOS apps. I have made a quick app as a first test. It runs perfect in the simulator but when running on my iPhone 4s the app runs and instantly i am set back to home screen.

Heres a link to my app if you could kindly view it and see what the problem could be because I have no clue.

http://netload.in/dateiGpnBm98FTY/FirstTest.zip.htm

Thank You

Comment: Debug the situation, If it's running fine on a the simulator, one of the first things to check in this situation is `Provisioning Profile` and or `Certificate` is properly made, and the `Bundle Idenfitier` matches the profile.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are running in debugging mode.

Comment: I don't have a developers account, I am running the app through a jailbroken device by fake code signing. Could this be the problem?. Or I think this method dose not work with iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Using developer account,it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set a Device frameworks, not a frameworks for simulator